# Contagem de objetos semelhantes no vetor

Tags: array

Gostaria de saber como contar sequências de diferentes dentro de um vetor contendo somente `0` e `1`.

Por exemplo, no vetor

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

a contagem daria o vetor `3` por que ele conta sequência iguais.

```
"1, 1, 1", "0, 0, 0", "1, 1" = 3
```

Comment: Você pode especificar melhor sua questão? Está usando alguma linguagem específica? Como é a estrutura de dados (de forma mais prática) que você recebe para validar?

Comment: @breno, conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que uma sequência pode ser formada também por um elemento, pode usar o seguinte:

```
int valorAtual = -1;
int total = 0;
for (int i=0 ; i<c.count() ; i++) {
  if (valorAtual != c[i])
    total++;
  valorAtual = c[i];
}
```

OBS: este algoritmo é genérico, já que não informou a linguagem